# jQuery inArray() disabling days with select option in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to disable specific days within FullCalendar. I have an array of dates from my database which will block or unblock days.

When i use the `inArray()` as below it blocks all days within the calendar. Not a `jQuery` guru so i need some help here please.

This is what i have so far;

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    var disabledDates = ['2017-03-17', '2017-03-23'];

    if($.inArray(disabledDates) !== -1) {
        swal({
          title: "Date is blocked",
          text: "Sorry, the maximum Daily Bookings have been reached. Please select another date.",
          type: "warning"
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#ModalAdd .start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#ModalAdd .end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        return true;
    };
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly accepted.

EDIT

I have edited my question above, but still cannot get this to work, it should just return either `true` or `false`.

The reason i am using `select: function` is the i just want the model not to show if there is a date in the array.

Why won't this work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with FullCalendar, but why are you using the `select` callback to disable a day? Shouldn't you be using the [dayRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/) to visually disable it (perhaps via a class) and [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectAllow/) to enforce the rule? My understanding is, if `select` fired, its already too late. Perhaps i'm wrong

Comment: Also, after looking at your code above, you are pusing the string `'disabled'` into the `disabledDates` array. Then you are checking that the same string is in the array which will always be true!

Comment: I have edited my question above, still no joy :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs this solution, i finally got it working.

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    var disabledDates = ['2017-03-17', '2017-03-23'];
    var selectedDate = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    if($.inArray(selectedDate, disabledDates) !== -1) {
        swal({
          title: "Date is blocked",
          text: "Sorry, the maximum Daily Bookings have been reached. Please select another date.",
          type: "warning"
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#ModalAdd .start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#ModalAdd .end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        return true;
    };
}
```